# Troubles using PHP5 hash feature

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a basic log in system. I am using the PHP5 Hash feature. Everything works ok when inserting into the database, it does its job correctly.

The problem now is that when I try to get the data from the database, it doesn't seem to pick it up. Here's my code and maybe this will give you some idea:

```
    // Create connection with the database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection to see if It connects, if not output an error message.
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// We are going to tell mysql to give us everything back related to user if we give it a username.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username=?");

//Pass the username to mysql. this is what the person entered into the form ($_POST['username'])
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['Username']);

//tell mysql to run our now completed statement and search for the user and return his info
$stmt->execute();

//great now we ask mysql to give us a variable that contains all the rows it found with that username
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//if there are 0 rows it means it couldn't find the username so the user doesn't exist
if($result->num_rows==0){
    echo "Looks like theres no username.";
}

//since it got to this part we know that it did find the username so we get the first row from the results
$myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();

//now we compare the password entered into the form ($_POST['password']) with the password in our db for the user ($myrow['Password'])
if(password_verify($_POST['Password'], $hashAndSalt)) {
    echo "It worked Shaun!";
} else {
    echo "nope";
}
```

As you can see I'm using the `password_verify()` feature. When I try to log in or get information from the database, it does not seem to match the correct information in the database from `$_POST`. So for example I'll enter "shaun" which is a table in the database, It comes back "nope" where it should come back "It worked".

**EDIT:**

$hashAndSalt is a variable which stores information into the database. Take the following:

```
//Here we are preparing to enter data into the database. Make sure to use all ? when entering data.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Rank) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    //Basically all data will be entered into the database.
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['Username'], $hashAndSalt, $Rank);

    $hashAndSalt = password_hash($_POST['Password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Comment: What is `$hashAndSalt`?

Comment: It is a variable which is used in register.php to insert data into the database. @zerkms

Comment: What is `register.php` and how is it relevant to the lines of code you pasted?

Comment: Your verification is just wrong...  it should be more like `password_verify($_POST['password'], $myrow['password_hash'])`.  $hashAndSalt sitting in register.php isn't how the system works.

Comment: @JohnGreen what is funny is that the comment right above is correct, but the code is not. Like the comment and code was written by different people.

Comment: @zerkms - lol.  I'd just seen that myself.  Of course, even the comment isn't quite right... you don't store the password in the DB, you store the hash + salt.

Comment: @Someone so how your main script is supposed to know that `$hashAndSalt` is a variable from some other file from some other script run? And what is the point to store the hash in database if you never retrieve it from there?

Comment: In short, in order to become operational, you'll need to move the $hashAndSalt declaration above the `bind_param` call.  And in your other code, you need to change the verification to verify against `$myrow['Password']`.  You'll probably need to rebuild a user, as your existing ones are likely garbage (or at least the hashed password).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I interpret you are trying to do from the code you provided, I have commented areas where you will need to provide additional code to display a UI or return a result. This is untested but should work.

```
<?php

include 'database_settings.php';

$mysqli = @new mysqli ( $mysql_hostname, $mysql_username,
    $mysql_password, $mysql_database );

if ( $mysqli->connect_errno > 0 ) {
    // return your error
    return;
}

if ( ( isset ( $_POST [ 'Username' ] ) ) && ( isset ( $_POST [ 'Password' ] ) ) ) {
    if ( ( strlen ( $_POST [ 'Username' ] ) > 0 ) && ( strlen ( $_POST [ 'Password' ] ) > 0 ) ) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username=?' );
        $stmt->bind_param ( 's', $_POST [ 'Username' ] );
        if ( !$stmt->execute () ) {
            // return your error
            return;
        }
        $result = $stmt->get_result ();
        if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
            while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
                if ( password_verify ( $_POST [ 'Password' ], $row [ 'Password' ] ) ) {
                    // login was successful
                } else {
                   // show the login form, wrong username or password
                }
                break;
            }
            $result->close ();
        } else {
            $result->close ();
            // show the login form, wrong username or password
        }
    } else {
        // show the login form, user has pressed submit without filling out the form
    }
} else {
    // show the login form
}

$mysqli->close ();
```